# Error with Google Create Cotact Using ApiV3

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I am working with google api version 3.0 and i am able to login successfully with gmail using c#. and getting access code also and after i am able to retrieve contact successfully. after that i want to add new Contact but i am not able to create new contact with below code.
public static Contact CreateContacts(ContactsRequest cr)
        {
            Contact newEntry = new Contact();

```
        // Set the contact's name.
        newEntry.Name = new Name()
        {
            FullName = "Harsh Desai",
            GivenName = "Harsh",
            FamilyName = "Desai",
        };
        newEntry.Content = "Notes";
        // Set the contact's e-mail addresses.
        newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
        {
            Primary = true,
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
            Address = "h@gmail.com"
        });
        newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail()
        {
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
            Address = "ha@example.com"
        });
        // Set the contact's phone numbers.
        newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Primary = true,
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
            Value = "9825277788",
        });
        newEntry.Phonenumbers.Add(new PhoneNumber()
        {
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome,
            Value = "0123654789",
        });
        // Set the contact's IM information.
        newEntry.PostalAddresses.Add(new StructuredPostalAddress()
        {
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsWork,
            Primary = true,
            Street = "1/Radhakrishna",
            City = "Surat",
            Postcode = "395007",
            Country = "India",
        });

        // Insert the contact.
        Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));

        Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);
        Console.WriteLine("Contact's ID: " + createdEntry.Id);
        return createdEntry;
    }
```

i am getting error on this line  Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry).
error was The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: Try changing phone number value format to "(xxx)xxx-xxxx". Also, are you sending contacts IM information too? I dont see it in your code.